# All modules aren't available after upgrading to Python 3.8.5

Tags: python-3.x, upgrade

I just upgraded the Python version from 3.8.4 to 3.8.5
And I faced a very major problem.
All modules that I already installed aren't available with the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module name'
```

So I tried to re-install the module with:

```
pip3 install module_name
```

And it returns an message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: module_name in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.8.5)
```

OS : Mac os
And I somehow figured it out that python libraries are saved on usr/lib/~
and there are two versions, one python 3.7.3 and python 3.8.5

And when I typed

```
python3 --version it printed out
Python 3.7.3
```

However, when I tried to install throgh pip3 it checked the module on python 3.8.5 which I want to use.

Therefore I think I need to change my default python3 version from python 3.7.3 to python 3.8.5.

How to change the default python version to python 3.8.5?
What's the problem here and how to fix it?

Comment: An answer to your question is likely to require more information about your Python environment. Can you tell us your OS, and how you installed both your old and new Python versions? It seems very likely that your new 3.8.5 install is looking somewhere different for its modules than 3.8.4, which probably shouldn't happen if they were packages from the same distribution. But if one comes from your OS and the other is a build you installed manually, then it's a lot less surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem once but with another version of python. The problem was about the module path: while pip install was using the correct path, my programs were using a different one, hence the error.
Try adding this to your program, where the path must be the absolute path to the folder containing the modules

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/search')
```

If it works you can fix it permanently by adding an environment variable with the path to the modules (the way to do it changes depending on the system)